# Reload Collection View without animation Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I reload only one cell without animation. I tried to use

```
horizontalItem.selectedType = horizontalItem.selectedType == .deselected ? .selected : .deselected
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

and change background and title colors, but change mades with animation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `performWithoutAnimation` method of `UIView`

```
 UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
 }
```